# How to find files not containing comment x?

Tags: spotlight, unix

I try to find all "*.xyz" files in folder x which does not have comment "abc". This code does the opposite. I would prefer to use Spotlight if possible. How i can do this?

Thanks

```
do shell script "mdfind -onlyin '/path/to/folder/x' kMDItemFinderComment == 'abc' kMDItemFSName == '*.xyz'"
```

Comment: I'd think it was enough to change the `==` to `!=`? Try `do shell script "mdfind -onlyin '/path/to/folder/x' kMDItemFinderComment != 'abc' kMDItemFSName == '*.xyz'"`.

Comment: @Emil That might work, but he asks too for a possible way of doing this with Spotlight.

Comment: @Thecafremo Sure, it's just a suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks for answers. Emil, i still have trouble with this. do shell script "mdfind -onlyin " & my_path & " kMDItemFSName == '*.scpt' kMDItemFinderComment != 'abc'" -->lists .scpt files but does not filter comments do shell script "mdfind -onlyin " & my_path & " kMDItemFinderComment != 'abc' kMDItemFSName == '*.scpt'" -->list all files not just .scpt

Answer (score 1):

The expression has to be a single argument. Subexpressions can be joined with `&&`:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemFinderComment!=abc&&kMDItemFSName=*.xyz' -onlyin /path/to/folder/x
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know `&&` was an operator (its counterpart, `||`, is also an operator). The expression can also be written with spaces to make it more readable: `'kMDItemFinderComment != abc && kMDItemFSName = *.xyz'`. A nice introduction to `mdfind` can be found here at http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/03/digging-deeper-mastering-spotlight-in-os-x/.

Answer (score 0):

While in the folder press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. This will bring up a new Finder window with the options to **Search** either in *This Mac* or in the current folder. Choose the name of the folder.

You'll be able to add new criteria to the search by pressing the Add (+) button on the right side of the search window. Clicking on the newly added criteria, a drop-down list will let you choose between the default ones. By choosing *Other* you'll be given a lot more options. Look for *Spotlight Comments*, and hit *Ok*.

When using Spotlight you can search for files which do not match certain criteria by typing the operand **NOT** before the *keyword*. So, once you've configured your *Search* options, just typing `NOT abc` in the *Spotlight comment* criteria will do the trick.